# OSX-like toolbar in window chrome?

Tags: macos, wxpython

Many OS X apps use some sort of iconized-tabs in the chrome of the menubar for their preference dialogs. For an wxPython app I would like to create such a preference dialog. Dropbox appears to be using wxPython (see also screenshot), so how would I create such a dialog myself?

[image: Dropbox preferences]

*Update:* After fiddling with `wx.Frame.CreateToolBar`, the frame begins to resemble the original. However, the style of the radio button (which I probably need for a `wx.Notebook`) is not what it should be. See also the gradient and borders of the 'General' tab in the image above. ([source code](https://gist.github.com/4110867))

[image: Somewhat Native OSX Toolbar]

Comment: did you get it to work after all? Including the gradient?

Comment: In the end we shut down this project. If you really need a native GUI, stick with the native tools.

Comment: That's a shame! I was hoping there'd be a solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

Dropbox doesn't use wx I'm pretty sure, but you can get this native toolbar with wx. You have to use ctypes and load in some core and carbon frameworks.

There is an [article](http://wiki.wxpython.org/NativeMacOSXToolbarSelection) in the wx wiki on how to do it

Comment: There was some talking about Dropbox using wx, but it could be wrong/outdated information. Nonetheless, the article you linked to uses the deprecated Carbon, whereas wxPython 2.9 uses Cocoa. Also could not get the example working using the relocated paths for both frameworks.

Comment: I'm using 2.8- but I'm pretty sure the example works under 2.9 as is

Comment: According to Robin Dunn (maker of wxPython), Dropbox uses wxPython for the setup wizard, preferences dialog, task bar icon, etc) - http://wxpython.org/blog/2009/03/09/time-to-kick-myself-again/

Comment: @Mike They used to, but I don't think they use wx anymore (I can't find any wx bits included in an install of the latest version)

Comment: @GP89 Retried, but to no avail. `AttributeError: dlsym(0x7f8378487260, GetWindowToolbar): symbol not found` on OSX Mountain Lion. See also my update with runnable code, it works but still needs some work.

Comment: The border and toggle appearance is what the ctypes stuff does in the article I linked. Maybe it only works with carbon although I'm sure there's a way to get it working with cocoa- I'll have a play if I get some time. I think the problem stems from the fact that the toolbar is a wx widgets toolbar which is from windows (i might be wrong), and it's only getting dressed up to look and appear native- it's not the native toolbar at all. I've got a mac app released using wx and the native toolbar works on Mountain Lion, and that just loads up the bits out of the Carbon framework.

Comment: What's the stacktrace that you get when running the code from the article?

Comment: @GP89 See pastebin.com/pzbzxkjz for the full stacktrace. This is on WX 2.9 / OSX 10.8.2.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is a custom wx.Dialog with a wx.Toolbook in it. See the wxPython demo package for an example or you can read my tutorial: http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2009/12/03/the-book-controls-of-wxpython-part-1-of-2/3/

UPDATE: I'm not sure if this still applies, but there is a wiki entry on something that sounds a lot like what the OP wants: http://wiki.wxpython.org/NativeMacOSXToolbarSelection

Comment: Thanks, however `wx.Toolbook` does not create a native toolbar, which is what I want to achieve. See also the updated question with the elaborated problem.